# Determine function $f(x)$

Tags: integration, functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Given $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\sin (kx)dx=\cases {3, \quad 0\le k \le 5 \\
                                               6, \quad 5 \le k\le 7 \\
                                               0, \quad k\ge7}
                                               $$

So, this is to be solved using the Fourier Transform approach.

I tried to use this technique,

If 
$$f(z)=\int_0^\infty(a(x)\cos (xz)+b(x)\sin (xz)) dx$$
then,

$$\implies a(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(z)\cos (xz)dz\\
\implies b(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(z)\sin (xz)dz$$

Based on this, I know that $b(x)$ function is the above $3$ case statements, but to determine $f(x)$, I need the value of $a(x)$ as well. How should I proceed from here using Fourier's method only? Or does there exist any other approach to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\sin (kx)dx=F_s(k)=\cases {3, \quad 0\le k \le 5 \\
                                               6, \quad 5 \le k\le 7 \\
                                               0, \quad k\ge7}
                                               $$
that is, $F_s(k)$ is the **Fourier sine transform** of $f(x)$ (see for example [Fourier cosine and sine transform](http://dsp-book.narod.ru/TAH/ch03.pdf)).

Thus, to calculate $f(x)$ you must obtain the inverse Fourier sine transform of $F_s(k)$:

$$f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty F_s(k)\sin (kx)dk=\frac{2}{\pi}\left(\int_0^53\sin (kx)dk+\int_5^7 6\sin (kx)dk\right)$$

and after simplifly

$$f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\,\,\frac{3 (1+\cos (5 x)-2 \cos (7 x))}{x}$$